# CommandLink with JSF Ajax requiring 2 clicks

Tags: java, ajax, jsf

I don't think this is the JSF issue with AJAX with a form within a form because I have only 1 form.

I looked at threads about Ajax and JSF rendering content and I tried multiple solutions with no luck.

Anyone see what is probably obvious that I am missing :-)

Thanks

**index.xhtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>
    <title>Manual</title>
    <h:outputStylesheet name="style.css" library="css" />
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <div id="page">
        <h:form id="myform"> 
        <div class="header" >
            <h:graphicImage library="img" name="Logo.gif" alt="Logo"/>
            <h1>Manual</h1>
        </div>

            <div class="menu">
        </div>

        <div class="nav">

            <h:outputText value="Navigation 1"/><br/>
            <p:commandLink value="Chapter100" action="#{contentBean.BuildContent}" update="content" >
                <f:ajax process="@this" render=":content" />
            </p:commandLink>

                    <!-- Add NewLine between links --> 
                    <h:outputText value="&#10;" />
            </div>
            </h:form>
            <div class="mycontent">
                <h:panelGroup id="content">
                    <h:outputText value="#{contentBean.content}" >
            </h:outputText>
                </h:panelGroup>
            </div>
        </div>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

**Bean**

```
@ManagedBean(name="contentBean")
@ViewScoped
public class ContentBean implements Serializable{
    private List<String> lTocInfo = new ArrayList();

    private String content = "Steve Newer 002 Content";

    public String getContent() 
    {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    public void BuildContent() throws Exception
    {
        this.setContent("Steve made it back from database");
    }     
}
```

Comment: The only think I find wrong is `<f:ajax process="@this" render=":content" />`. You're basically mixing JSF and PF together: JSF's `<f:ajax>` has `execute` and `render`, PF's `<p:ajax>` has `process` and `update`. Moreover, PF has its own AJAX framework designed to be used with its components, so you must either use `<p:ajax>` in this case, or use the shortcut `process` and `update` attributes of `<p:commandLink>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use  `<f:ajax>` inside primefaces button as by default it is an ajax request (unless you want turn off the ajax request you may set ajax attribute to false). You can use update and process attributes.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that to resolve that, You can also to use in  the ajax the following code in the Link:

```
<p:commandLink value="Chapter100" action="#{contentBean.BuildContent}">
                <f:ajax execute="@form" event="blur" render="content" />
</p:commandLink>
```